# Debugging PAS files in C++ Builder 64 bit project, Rad Studio 10.4

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I found this very good link for stepping through .pas files in a c++ builder 32 bit project [Using Delphi library with C++ Builder](https://www.arbinada.com/en/node/1555)

This works fine for 32 bit projects, but it doesn't enable debugging of pas files in 64 bit application.  Are there additional steps required to enable to pas files to be debugged in 64 bit applications?

If so, can you please advise what these additional configurations are.

Comment: Maybe, not an answer: what if you open the library sources at Delphi, then do "Attach to process" debugging? Keeping in mind you launched that C++ app with exactly the binary you have built by Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and the only way we have managed to debug a 64b Delphi dll is by building our project using Lazarus (based on FreePascal).

With Lazarus you can debug the dll using the attach to process.

With RAD 10 or 11 we have not been able to debug in 64b, and Embarcadero told us that debugging 64b is not supported.